# jQuery - Cannot Remove Class

Tags: jquery, css

I cannot seem to remove the class 'foo' and I do not understand why. When the user clicks on .foo jQuery is suppose to remove .foo. At first glance it seems to work as the text is no longer red. However, clicking .foo several times will result in the alert box appearing thus meaning .foo has not completely been removed. I do not understand why this is happening.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.foo').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('foo');
        alert('Class .foo should have been removed. Why is this alert still appearing?');
    });             
});​
```

html:

```
<p class="foo">foo</p>​
```

css:

```
.foo { color: red; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nvrp8/

Comment: Works for me fine in chrome. The alert still appears because that's what you told it to do in the funciton. onClick>removeClass>alert()

Comment: Yes, after lots of clarification I know understand that removing the class would not remove the listener that is attached to the element. I guess my question should have been 'how to remove a listener that is attached to an element'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use on() it actually evaluates the selector for each click because the event is bound to body, not to ".foo"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".foo",function() {
        $(this).removeClass('foo');
        alert( 'Class .foo should have been removed. Why is this alert still appearing?' );       
    });             
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nvrp8/8/

Answer (score 5):

You need to unbind the click listener.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nvrp8/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.foo').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('foo');
        alert( 'Class .foo should have been removed. Why is this alert still appearing?' );     
        $(this).unbind('click');        
    });             
});​
```

Comment: Is there another alternative then unbinding the click listener? I intend to continue to use the click event listener on .foo.

Comment: @icu222much The click listener is only unbound for the current element.  It will continue to work on other .foo elements.  http://jsfiddle.net/Nvrp8/6/

Comment: @icu222much You don't have to unbind it at all. The class is removed without unbinding, as it should. See the jsfiddle in my answer.

Comment: @kdg123 Yes, but I need to use the click listener on all .foo elements

Comment: @JeffFabiny Thank you Jeff. I will take a look at your fiddle.

Comment: @RyanKinal Thank you Ryan. I will investigate delegation.

Comment: @kdg123 Right, but his issue isn't removing the listener, just the class. The dialogs I added were before and after the class removal, to demonstrate that it did in fact happen.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `$('.foo')`, you get a static set of elements that have `class="foo"` *at that time*. So, even if you `removeClass('foo')` from those elements at a later time, you still bound the listener to that original set of elements.

If you want to change that behavior, consider looking at `.on` or `.delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

It's working just fine, the listener is still bound. http://jsfiddle.net/Nvrp8/5/

Comment: I am confused why the alert is still appearing even though that element has .foo removed from it. From my understanding, the click() function should only be toggled if the user clicks on .foo class. If the .foo is removed, how come the alert is still toggled?

Comment: @icu222much The listener is attached to the element still!  It doesn't matter that it doesn't have the class .foo anymore.  It may not have that class, but it still has the listener bound to it.

Comment: @kdg123 Ah, I see. I understand. I think `.on` should solve my problem.

Comment: @icu222much Perhaps you mean you want to remove the class AND the listener, but ONLY on this element? That is, clicking .foo will remove the class and listener, but other .foo elements will continue to have their listeners?

Comment: @JeffFabiny I wanted to unassociate class on this element, but keep the listener. My goal is that once the class has been removed from this .foo element, the alert box will stop appearing. `.on` has solved my problem.